# Python Crash Course new_entry.save() causing me errors

Tags: python, django

So I'm following a book called Python Crash Course. And I'm currently working on its Django project, and I am encountering a problem that's apparently in the views.py. Here is the entire code for views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from .models import Topic, Entry
from .forms import TopicForm, EntryForm

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/index.html')

@login_required
def topics(request):
    topics = Topic.objects.filter(owner=request.user).order_by('date_added')
    context = {'topics': topics}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topics.html', context)

@login_required
def topic(request, topic_id):
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    if topic.owner != request.user:
        raise Http404

    entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
    context = {'topic': topic, 'entries': entries}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topic.html', context)

@login_required
def new_topic(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = TopicForm()
    else:
        form = TopicForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_topic = form.save(commit=False)
            new_topic.owner = request.user
            new_topic.save()
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:topics'))

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/new_topic.html', context)

@login_required
def new_entry(request, topic_id):
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)

    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = EntryForm()
    else:
        form = EntryForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_entry = form.save(commit=False)
            new_entry.topic = topic
            new_entry.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:topic', args=[topic_id]))

    context = {'topic': topic, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/new_entry.html', context)

@login_required
def edit_entry(request, entry_id):
    entry = Entry.objects.get(id=entry_id)
    topic = entry.topic
    if topic.owner != request.user:
        raise Http404

    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = EntryForm(instance=entry)
    else:
        form = EntryForm(instance=entry, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:topic', args=[topic.id]))

    context = {'entry': entry, 'topic': topic, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/edit_entry.html', context)
```

And here is the error I'm getting when I try to submit a new entry:

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/new_entry/4/
Django Version: 2.0.2
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such table: main.learning_logs_topic__old
Exception Location: C:\Users\Gilbert\PycharmProjects\GGprojects\django\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute, line 303
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Gilbert\PycharmProjects\GGprojects\django\ll_env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.0
```

I think the problem is with the line 56, `new_entry.save()`. Is there I way I can solve this and successfully add a new entry to a topic?

Comment: You did not make migrations, or migrate the database correctly.

Comment: I see. I'll try to migrate the database again.

Comment: So I tried re-migrating and I'm still getting the same error. What should I do now?

Comment: Did you run both commands, `python manage.py make migrations learning_logs`, and then `python manage.py migrate`? If that doesn't work, what made you think the issue might be with `new_entry.save()`?

Comment: Yes, I ran both `python manage.py make migrations learning_logs` and `python manage.py migrate`. And I also think it has something to do with `new_entry.save()`, but I can't tell what is it. I double-checked all the python files and didn't find any typos or mistakes in them.